# Can access a list declared within a function inside another function withing the first function, but not a variable without using global attribute

Tags: python

Class 'Test' contains function 'test_variables'.
Functions 'update_d' and 'update_a' are declared within 'test_variables()'.
Variable 'index' is initialized to 0 in 'test_variables'
List A [1,2] is initialized in 'test_variables'
'update_d' and 'update_a' updates 'index' and prints it.
I can access elements of list A without using the global attribute,
but to access 'index' I have declared'global index' within 'update_d' and 'update_a'. 
Why can I not access the variable index without global but can access a list?

```
index=0
class Test():
    def test_variables():
        def update_d():
            global  index
            index=index+1+A[0]
            print(index)

        def update_a():
            global  index
            index=index+1+A[1]
            print(index)            
        index=0
        A=[1,2]
        update_d()
        update_a()
    test_variables()
```

Comment: Have you ever worked with classes before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the `global` keyword is only needed when you are *writing* to a variable. Inside `test_variable()` you have defined a NEW variable named `index`, though it seems your intent was to write to the variable defined outside that scope.

When you read from a variable name, Python starts in the innermost scope and if the name isn't found, continues looking in the containing scopes.

When you write to a variable name, Python only looks locally and creates a new variable if one of that name isn't found. The `global` keyword tells Python that the local scope should reference that name globally on assignment.

For this reason, global variables work best as constants, and variables you need to change should probably be passed in to a function as a parameter and the new value returned.

Answer (score 0):

The list `A` (in addition to `update_a` and `update_b`) is defined within `Test`, while `index` is not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct way of using classes.

**Code:**

```
class Test:
    A = (1, 2)

    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

    def update_d(self):
        self.index += 1 + self.A[0]
        print(self.index)

    def update_a(self):
        self.index += 1 + self.A[1]
        print(self.index)

    def test_variables(self):
        self.update_d()
        self.update_a()


idx = 0

tst = Test(idx)
tst.test_variables()
```

Provided code does same as yours but with correct usage of classes.